# Use Sendgrid to send email with attachment from a form

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I am trying to send an attachment from a form to an email, using the Sendgrid web api.

However, I have no clue on how to edit the following code in order to make use of the input file of the form.

Any help please?

```
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to'        => 'the recipient email',
    'subject'   => 'New Careers',
    'html'      => $email,
    'text'      => $email,
    'from'      => 'the sender email',
  );



$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';


$session = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
```

Comment: They offer a php api that makes that very easy: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/USE_CASES.md#attachments

Comment: @jeroen can I stick to the web api that I am using?

Answer (score 0):

This solution may help you.

```
if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { // php 5.5+
  $cFile = curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path);
} else { // 
  $cFile = '@' . realpath($file_name_with_full_path);
}
$post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=> $cFile);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Here is [Reference URL](http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/)

Comment: i couldn't make it work... Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @EnexoOnoma you can add one more variable in  `$param` like `'file_contents'=> $cFile` and $cFile content file path.

Comment: have you check file is exist on path or not? or have you try to set static path of file?